Door sweep material replacement
Any idea what the material is called that needs replacing on this door sweep? It looks simple to replace I'm just not sure what to buy.


It was simply fiber-reinforced rubber or vinyl. Doesn't much matter that you match that exactly--you'll be replacing the metal rail also. Just get something that seems to be good quality. You'll be screwing it on at new screw locations anyway.

So you're saying I shouldn't just buy new material I should replace the entire rail and material? This one works well minus the worn out gap. Any idea where I would find one similar or a link? Thnx

@user1179567 Yes.  You are unlikely to be able to find just the flexible strip.  It is likely integrated into the metal rail—could be mechanical, or adhesive—and you are unlikely to be able to achieve the same capture strength by simply replacing it.  Just do a search for "exterior door sweep" or similar.  Perhaps if you take it off there's a manufacturer's name stamped on it somewhere, but anything that fits would be just as good.

Any hardware store has this type of thing on hand.
